# Delete running executable

Tags: c#, exe, delete-file, kill-process

I have [almost the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700571/delete-running-file-in-windows)

I have two files a.exe in folder c:\one and a.exe in c:\two, both are running, but I want to delete the file only in the first folder

(If not this condition, I could use

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("a.exe"))
                process.Kill();
```

and then delete the file
)

For [almost the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700571/delete-running-file-in-windows) was the answer RunOnce registry key, but I don't care if the user logs on or not, I just want to delete it now. Can you help me?

Comment: I'm not sure the links are the good ones, don't you think ?

Comment: if(!process.ProcessStartInfo.FileName.Contains("one"))process.Kill(); Maybe?

Comment: @CallumBradbury That would kill other processes with the word `"one"` in them.

Comment: i am trying to find the link

Comment: so the procstartinfo gives the full name?

Comment: @DGibbs I know, it's a basic single line response that Poly can use to come up with his actual answer - that's why I didn't submit it as a true answer. Point is, you can get the information via ProcessStartInfo and filter based on that.

Comment: @CallumBradbury That's fine, but the point is still worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to figure out which process corresponds to which instance of a.exe?

Seems like you can do this with the `Process.MainModule.FileName` property:

```
var exeToDelete = "...";
var exeProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(exeToDelete))
    .SingleOrDefault(p => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(p.MainModule.FileName, exeToDelete));
if (exeProcess != null) { exeProcess.Kill(); }

File.Delete(exeToDelete);
```

Comment: works! thanks very much but I used Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension